# MVC ViewUserControl not retrieving css stylesheets

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-2

I have Created New MVC2 ViwUserControl 
and I have added new css file to ~/Content/Styles folder in my solution explorer.
but my user control is not retrieving CSS files

```
 <link href="~/Content/Styles/demo_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="~/Content/Styles/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="~/Content/Styles/demo_validation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="~/Content/Styles/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="~/Content/Styles/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="~/Content/Styles/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

any ideas/help appreciated?

when i debug through the firbug i'm seeing **404 not found** error for these files

Answer (score 1):

The preceding `tilde` is throwing your code off ...

Change:

```
<link href="~/ ...
```

To:

```
<link href="/ ...
```

The tilde `~` is a server-side construct commonly used in ASP.Net WebForms with code like:

```
<img runat="server" src="~/Images/foo.png" />.
```

---

In MVC the standard is to use `@Url.Content(" ... ");` so:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Styles/demo_page.css")"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `~/` in html. the only works with server-side function that support that vritual path. Remove `~`